# cache library for Objective-C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there an existing library for Objective C (that can be used on the iPhone) containing a cache implementation that:

- allows to limit the number of elements
- removes elements with an LRU algorithm if the limit is reached
- optional: allows to remove all elements older than X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [NSCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? It should allow you to setup rules like you're wanting.

Comment: that looks like what I was searching for, I have Googled for half an hour and did not stumble upon it. How did you find it?

Comment: the documentation hints at some auto-removal policies without any details. The Gnu NextStep implementation (http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSCache.m) uses an access counter. Not exactly LRU, but good enough for now. But I still find it strange that I couldn't find that by Googling

Comment: I heard it mentioned in a WWDC talk this year. I've used it in a couple of things since then, works well.

Comment: Pity, it doesn't support LRU.